# Project template in liftoff

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, command-line-interface

I am trying to use https://github.com/thoughtbot/liftoff for my new projects.
I created .liftoffrc file in my path/Developer/iOS directory and when I run liftoff command in this directory, it creates swift project but I declared

```
project_template: objc
```

in my .liftoffrc configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

Just use liftoff --template objc command.